# Disallow editing but allow page extraction in Java iText / PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iText to generate PDF files.  I want to disallow editing of the PDF, but allow the reader to extract pages. Here's my code to set encryption:

`writer.setEncryption(null, null, 0xffffffff,  PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);`

The third parameter specifies permissions.  I'm using 0xffffffff instead of the individual iText flags ALLOW_PRINTING etc. This will ask iText to enable everything.  But this is what I get in the PDF file:

[image]

I should think I should be allowed to enable extraction but disable editing, but am not certain.  Here are the permissions bits per Adobe:
[image]
[image]

(From [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), but be warned it's 30 meg)

So turn off bits 6 and 11 but leave on the others (especially bits 5 and 10), and that would turn off editing but allow extraction.  In any case, by specifying 0xffffffff I would think that everything would be allowed; but instead everything *except* extraction is allowed.

I've skimmed the iText source code for setting permissions and don't see anything that would cause this.  Here is the relevant code from PdfEncryption.setupAllKeys:

```
permissions |= (revision == STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128 || revision == AES_128 || revision == AES_256) ? 0xfffff0c0
        : 0xffffffc0;
permissions &= 0xfffffffc;
```

The first line is doing an OR and so wouldn't remove any permissions; the second line is setting the two right-most bites to 0, per the PDF specification.

I'm wondering if it's an iText thing, a PDF thing or if I'm doing something else wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue already has been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124098/problems-setting-rights-setencryption-within-pdf).

> Using encryption actually is counter-productive as it can only be used to remove permissions, not to add them.

According to this, it might be helpful to completely unlock the PDF first:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.toURI().toURL());
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(
    file.getAbsolutePath().replace(".pdf", "_UNLOCKED.pdf")));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Afterwards you can grab the output and start from scratch (mess around with the permission bits). Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** If you don't have access to the password, the [iText sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) can be modified. Simply comment out `if (!reader.isOpenedWithFullPermissions()) throw ...` (line 121 and 122 in version 5.5.0) in `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp`.

Comment: *Simply comment out line 121 and 122* - I assume you mean the lines `if (!reader.isOpenedWithFullPermissions()) throw ...`. That edit is **not** necessary, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666577/opening-password-protected-pdf-file-with-itextsharp/17694943#17694943), simply set `PdfReader.unethicalreading = true` after making sure that you are indeed entitled to ignore the restrictions coming with the password protection.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @mkl. Unfortunately this does **not** allow 'Changing the Document', 'Document Assembly', 'Content Copying' and 'Page Extraction' (what changing the sources does). At least that's what I experienced.

Comment: That would surprise as both essentially do the same, they both prevent the exception.